# CakePHP: Validate login form

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to validate a login form but I get error on form: Notice (8): Undefined variable: user [APP/Template\Users\login.ctp, line 5]

What could be?

**login.ctp**:

```
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-5  large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
        <?= $this->Form->create($user); ?>

            <?= $this->Form->input('email' ,array('id' =>'email')); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password'), array('id' => 'password')); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->submit('Login', array('class' => 'button')); ?>

        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

login function on **UsersController.php**:

```
public function login()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();

            if($user)
            {

                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'comentario']);
            }

            // Erro no Login

            $this->Flash->error('Erro de autenticação');
        }


    }
```

**UPDATE login function located in UsersController.php**

```
public function login()
    {
          $user = $this->Auth->identify();

        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {


            if($user)
            {

                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'comentario']);
            }

            // Erro no Login

            $this->Flash->error('Erro de autenticação');
        }


    }
```

**Auth Configuration:**

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
            'fields' => [
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password'
            ]

            ]

            ],
            'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
            ]

            ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$user` is a reference to a variable and is undefined in your view. If you are creating a form for users, then the standard convention would be :

```
<?= $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
```

which will implicitly post to the same action that rendered the view.

**Update:**

You are calling auth for the `$user` before you check if the form is posted, so it will throw an undefined error before the form is submitted, when the view is rendered normally. I'm not overly familiar with 3.x, so you may or may not need to explicitly pass `$this->request->data` to the auth function. The method should be something like the following:

```
    public function login()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if($user)
        {

            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'comentario']);
        }

        // Erro no Login

        $this->Flash->error('Erro de autenticação');
    }
    else{
        //do something else here
    }
}
```

From the 3.x [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in)

> Identifying Users and Logging Them In AuthComponent::identify() You
>   need to manually call $this->Auth->identify() to identify the user
>   using credentials provided in request. Then use $this->Auth->setUser()
>   to log the user in, i.e., save user info to session.
>
> When authenticating users, attached authentication objects are checked
>   in the order they are attached. Once one of the objects can identify
>   the user, no other objects are checked. A sample login function for
>   working with a login form could look like:

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'), [
                'key' => 'auth'
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This remove the error but the validation doesn't works. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Post your auth configuration, and the error you are getting now

Comment: Posted. I'm getting the same undefined variable error.

Comment: Oh sorry, when I put this <?= $this->Form->create('User'); ?> I don't get any error but the validation doesn't works. And using  <?= $this->Form->create($user); I get undefined variable error.

Comment: I'm getting the same result. when I put  this code <?= $this->Form->create('User'); ?> the error is removed, but when I use this <?= $this->Form->create($user); ?> I get undefined variable error. Thanks for attention.

Comment: I'm getting the same result.